# Next.js yarn build failed due to plotly.js (Build error occurred ReferenceError: self is not defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, build-error, plotly.js

I am getting the following error when I try to build the Next.js app for production using `yarn build` command. But it is working fine in the development server (when using `yarn dev` command). I am using `react-plotly.js` library for generating plot graphs in this react app.

Use of react-plotly lib:

```
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

return(
  <>
   <Plot data={[data]} layout={layout} />
  </>
)
```

Here is the error:

```
> Build error occurred
ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

[image]

I have researched the issues on plotly.js git repository and google similar problem but seems with no result. Any ideas why Next.js yarn build failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next Js uses server side rendering, due to this a number of libs reliant on native objects (commonly the window object) wont work as expected.

https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/40

It seems plotly does not work with ssr but there is another component that should
https://github.com/aulneau/next.js-with-react-plotly.js

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Dynamic import with no SSR works for me. You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using `lazy` to lazy-load the component and `Suspense` from React 18 to render the component.

[My solution in Remix JS shown here](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/272#issuecomment-1449356710)